# How does python venv manage C++ dependencies

Tags: python, c++, binding, python-venv

I'm using a library which offers a python wrapper to a c++ executable.

I installed it (https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3) using venv (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) - and all is working great.

I'm considering trying to build https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3

From the root of the venv folder I found gym/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybullet.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so. I'm guessing this is the executable that is invoked eventually from python.

What steps are involved in calling from Python to the correct external binary executable? How does `import pybullet as p` resolve to  gym/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybullet.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so?

This seems to be close to the end of the c++ world; but I can't find the right key word searches to see exactly how that allows python usages.

Thanks

Comment: Do you look for this: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python just looks for correctly named dynamic libraries in PYTHONPATH, loads such library and uses predefined interface

for further info :
https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html

Comment: Looks like direct copy paste from my answer. @brent have you thoughtfully chosen this answer thas the accepted one?

Answer (score 1):

In short words: C-python just looks for correctly named dynamic libraries in PYTHONPATH, loads such library and uses predefined interface to understand what exactly from this library shall be visible as contents of the module inside Python.

In long words details of how to prepare such shared object and what are required contents of it are described in https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html

So venv just puts dynamic library in directory which is part of PYTHONPATH of virtual environment.